# Google oAuth login using jmeter

Tags: oauth, jmeter

I have just started using jmeter and want to run performance tests on my application which uses google auth as a login option(oAuth 2.0), What are the steps to implement login using google auth on jmeter?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain so called [`token`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and add it to your request as [`Authorization` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) using [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) like:

[image]

With regards to how to obtain the token - it depends on your application configuration, if you're lucky enough and the token is more or less permanent - you can obtain it using [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/?pli=1)

If the token lifetime is limited and/or your application uses for complex flows - you will have to implement this flow in JMeter, the implementations vary and can be i.e. [Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) or [Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) or [Client-Side Aplications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent), you need to ask around and determine the exact flow.

Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article to learn more about bypassing OAuth login challenge in JMeter tests